# Vertex Cover with minimum degree 1

Tags: algorithms

> In Special Vertex Cover, we are given an undirected graph $G$, and an integer $k\in \mathbb{N_0}$.  The objective is to decide whether there exists a vertex cover $S$ of $G$ of size at most $k$ such that $G[S]$ (the subgraph of G induced by S) has minimum degree 1 i.e the at the subgraph that induced only by the vertices of $S$ there are no isolated vertices.

I want to design an $O(4^k)$-sized kernel for Special Vertex Cover. but I'm stuck because any reduction rule that I'm trying to apply doesn't save the equivalent of one of the requirements.
if I try to remove only 1 vertex at a time the requirement that the minimum degree 1 doesn't save. and if I try to remove 2 vertices the requirement that the set will be at size k doesn't save.

so far I've figured that:

1. if there is an isolated vertex then I need to remove it.
2. if there 2 isolated neighbors then I need to remove them and decrease k by 2.

what else can do?

Comment: Does it really require minimum degree equal to 1? Or is it that the minimum degree must be at least 1? If it requires equal to 1, why not apply your reduction and then just add a vertex or two at the end?

Comment: @JimN the minimum degree most ti be at least 1 i.e there are not isolated vetexs

Comment: If the minimum degree must be 1 or higher, then why is rule(1) (removing all isolated vertices) not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @JimN No the graph induced by the solution has a minimum degree of 1.

Comment: If there is an isolated vertex, then there is no solution.

Comment: @ArturRiazanov Still may be a solution becuse there are not a edge to cover in case of isolated vertex.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify it.  Don't leave clarifications in the comments -- especially ones that contradict statements made in the question.  Instead, [edit] the question so everything readers need to know is contained in the question, and they don't have to read teh comments.

Comment: @D.W. thank you very much, I added the clarification to the post, that question came as a side question at my Pramterized Algorithm course, I tried to find the source but I haven't found and I'm thinking that my lecturer came up with that question.

Comment: If you heard it from your lecturer, then you should be crediting your lecturer.  No one expects you to read your lecturer's mind; but we do expect you to give credit to the source you are copying it from.

Answer (score 1):

**Reduction Rule:** Let $T$ be the set of vertices such that each vertex has a degree of at least $k+1$ and for every vertex $u \in T$ there exist a vertex $v \in T$ such that there is an edge $(u,v) \in E$. All the vertices in $T$ belong to the vertex cover and already satisfy the "degree $1$" condition. Merge all the vertices in $T$. Let the merged vertex be $t$. Add a new vertex $w$ with $k$ pendant vertices and add an edge $(t,w)$ to the graph. Decrease $k$ by $|T|-2$.

Let $A \subseteq V \setminus T$ be the set of vertices each with a degree of at least $k+1$. Then, $A$ forms an independent set and $|A| \leq k$.

Let $B = V \setminus (A \cup T)$. Then, every vertex in $B$ has a degree at most $k$. Therefore, the graph spanned by $B$ contains at most $k^2$ edges; otherwise, the graph is a "no" instance. Let $B' \subseteq B$ be the set of vertices spanned by these edges. The remaining vertex set $R = B \setminus B'$ forms an independent set. Therefore, $A$ and $R$ form a bipartite graph. Let $x$ and $y$ be two vertices in $R$ that share the same set of neighbors in $A$. Then, one of these vertices can be removed. Using this reduction, the size of $R$ can be reduced to $2^k$. Overall, the number of vertices in the reduced graph is at most $2^k + O(k^2) = O(2^k)$. And, the number of edges is at most $O(k \cdot 2^k)$. I think the number of edges can be further reduced to $O(2^k)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131829/discussion-between-inuyasha-yagami-and-orifrid).